# Transactional Replication in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

We need to set up `transactional replication` in `SQL server 2014`, `Enterprise edition` so that:

Database to be replicated from **Publisher** which is approximately 2 TB in size. This would be used 24*6. Here we also need to use sql server encryption. Server has

> Approx 480 GB of RAM and 48 logical processors.

1) **Subscriber** to be used as Reporting server where users will only be doing their reporting tasks. This is to be implemented so as to avoid any additional overload on the primary server above. Data to be replicated should not be the encrypted as the SAN drive on this server is already encrypted. storage of around 3 TB.

2) Same database needs to be replicated on another server, which for almost 300 users would be available as VPN mode,connecting to it. This server would be required to have encryption data to be replicated.

I believe above 2 would be possible from a single publisher to 2 different subscriber via transactional replication. Please correct me if  am wrong as we would be setting this up for first time in SQL server 2014.

Also, would above be the best strategy for DR. The client does not agree with clustering. So we have suggested replication to be the best approach as per above requirements.

Please provide your expert recommendations that can be helpful for us to set up the above requirement.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using ? if using Enterprise then AlwaysON would be a good option to consider. Also are you sure you want to replicate the whole **2TB** database ? Any schema changes will require a snapshot and that means a looong downtime.

Comment: @Kin, that information is yet to be gathered from the client. But as far as we have fetched the info, they want one of the servers to be used for reporting purpose. So for reporting, i believe we can go with replication. But if its enterprise, can we have Always on configured for the VPN servers along with replication set up on another server.

Comment: No, you only need AlwaysON if you have enterprise edition. AlwaysON supports **readable secondaries** that can be used for reporting. Many more possibilities open up once you finalize what edition you want.

Comment: @Kin, thanks for that info, i will check on always on. Also, we have 2 points to consider, client agrees on 24 hour downtime but almost zero data loss. considering this does always on holds and upper hand on replication, however, i will edit my question once get to know on the edition info.

Comment: The only downside of replication is when it comes to snapshot or when your publisher is very busy there by distribution agent is not able to keep up. In my company, we have implemented T-Rep with AlwaysON. As I said, you have to really think about all possiblities when architecting big systems.

Comment: @Kin, it is enterprise. But to use Always on, do we need some sort of clustering to be set up. Because client has said no to any form of clustering and we are also looking for the reason why so. In case Always ON cannot be used, will a single publisher with 2 subscribers a good option and if we can use always on, please let me know how can i get that up to use for reporting and other OLAP purpose.

Comment: First decide and then update your question. This way we dont have to **guess** anything :-)

Comment: @Kin, yes we would not be using clustering. i am not sure if we need those three servers to be in cluster to avail ALWAYS ON option. If not, then what could be the best method to avail HA with DR.(24hr downtime with min amount of data loss)